# Async Await | Can't have server wait for response from database before using authenification

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous, async-await

So i'm having a problem where i'm attempting to have an async call to my database to check if the username and password of an account exist before then checking to see if they are valid.

I'm running into the problem that the server skips my database call and then proceeds to the check before the information from the database is grabbed.

The code:

```
class HandlerGenerator {
  login (req, res) {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let checkUsername = "";
    let checkPassword = "";

    var lData = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
      };
    // For the given username fetch user from DB
    var db = req.db;
    var getUser = async () => {
        var result = await (
          User.findOne(lData , function(err, userLogin){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return
              }
              console.log(userLogin);
              console.log("------====----");
              console.log(userLogin.username);
              checkUsername = userLogin.username;
              checkPassword = userLogin.password;

              console.log("------====----");
              console.log(checkUsername);
              console.log(checkPassword);
            })
        );
        console.log("--00--");
        console.log('result' + result)
        return result;
    };

    console.log("does this work?");
    if (username && password) {
      console.log("------==2==----");
      console.log(checkUsername)
      console.log(checkPassword)
      if (username === checkUsername && password === checkPassword) {
        let token = jwt.sign({username: username},
          config.secret,
          { expiresIn: '24h' // expires in 24 hours
          }
        );
        // return the JWT token for the future API calls
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Authentication successful!',
          token: token
        });
      } else {
        res.send(403).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Incorrect username or password'
        });
      }
    } else {
      res.send(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Authentication failed! Please check the request'
      });
    }
  }
  index (req, res) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Index page'
    });
  }
}
```

When I run this the "Does this work?" Comment always runs first and i'm confused on what I am messing up

Comment: you can't just wait anything, it has to be a promise.

Comment: You can only `await` a promise.

Comment: Also you only *defined* the function, you never *call* it or resolve the result.

Comment: Let me get this right I need to call the get user?

Comment: I'm fairly new to async promises could you explain it quickly I was under the assumption that by setting the variable I was calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main issues here.

First, `async` returns an `AsyncFunction`, which returns a `Promise` when called. This means that at this point, nothing in `getUser` has been executed. Not only you need to actually call `getUser` to start running what is inside it, but you also need to await the result, otherwise you have absolutely no guarantee that the execution will be over. 
Instead of going through this trouble, making your `login` function `async` seems a more reasonable choice, as you are trying to do asynchronous operations inside it. You could then remove the `getUser` function and only keep the `var result = await User.findOne(....)` part.

The other issue, as multiple persons said in the comments, is that you need to `await` on a `Promise`.
Looking at your function call, it looks like your `findOne` functions uses a callback rather than a promise. Do check the documentation, some libraries support both and might indeed return a promise if you do not pass in any callback.
If it does, you should not pass any callback. The result of the "awaited" call should be `userLogin`.

Otherwise, wrapping the function so that it returns a promise is straightforward.
The basic pattern is as follows

```
// this is the function that we want to wrap
function funcToWrap(someParam, callback) {
   // does stuff
   callback(null, "some result");
}

// this is the wrapper
function wrappedFunction(someParam) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    funcToWrap(someParam, (err, res) => {
      if (err === null) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
```

This transforms your callback-based function into a promise-based one. You can then of course `await` on `wrappedFunc` and use it as any other promise.

This is such a common pattern that a lot of libraries already implement this functionality. For example, the Promise library Bluebird provides a `promisify` function which does exactly this.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

So instead of writing all of this yourself, you could simply write

```
var wrappedFunction = Promise.promisify(funcToWrap);
```